# How to view the virtual function table of an inherited Java class

Tags: java, virtual-functions, dispatch-table

I have the following java code:

```
class Father  {
    public void walk(int x) { System.out.format("Fwalk %d", x); }
    public void run (int x) { System.out.format("Frun  %d", x); }
    public void swim(int x) { System.out.format("Fswim %d", x); }
}
class Son extends Father {
    public void swim(int x) { System.out.format("Fswim %d", x); }
    public void cook(int x) { System.out.format("Scook %d", x); }
    public void run (int x) { System.out.format("Frun  %d", x); }
}
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Father f = new Father();
        f.run(1);
        f.swim(2);
        Son s = new Son();
        s.run(3);
        s.swim(4);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for the *actual offsets* of `swim` and `run` in the virtual function tables. When I use an equivalent C++ code, I am able to do that *easily* with *objdump*:

```
 663     f->run(1);
 664  8c3:   48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
 665  8c7:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
 666  8ca:   48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax <------ offset 8 for father::run
```

And the *same offset* for inherited class:

```
 689     s->run(3);
 690  914:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
 691  918:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
 692  91b:   48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax <------ offset 8 for son::run
```

When I use [Apache's class utility](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bcel/bcel/5.2), I get something close (the pool constants)

```
1)CONSTANT_Methodref[10](class_index = 11, name_and_type_index = 20)
2)CONSTANT_Class[7](name_index = 21)
3)CONSTANT_Methodref[10](class_index = 2, name_and_type_index = 20)
4)CONSTANT_Methodref[10](class_index = 2, name_and_type_index = 22)
5)CONSTANT_Methodref[10](class_index = 2, name_and_type_index = 23)
6)CONSTANT_Class[7](name_index = 24)
7)CONSTANT_Methodref[10](class_index = 6, name_and_type_index = 20)
8)CONSTANT_Methodref[10](class_index = 6, name_and_type_index = 22)
9)CONSTANT_Methodref[10](class_index = 6, name_and_type_index = 23)
10)CONSTANT_Class[7](name_index = 16)
11)CONSTANT_Class[7](name_index = 25)
12)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("<init>")
13)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("()V")
14)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("Code")
15)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("LineNumberTable")
16)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("main")
17)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("([Ljava/lang/String;)V")
18)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("SourceFile")
19)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("main.java")
20)CONSTANT_NameAndType[12](name_index = 12, signature_index = 13)
21)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("Father")
22)CONSTANT_NameAndType[12](name_index = 26, signature_index = 27)
23)CONSTANT_NameAndType[12](name_index = 28, signature_index = 27)
24)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("Son")
25)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("java/lang/Object")
26)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("run")
27)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("(I)V")
28)CONSTANT_Utf8[1]("swim")
```

It seems like the entries to the virtual function table are name-based ("run", "swim"). Is this really so? For completion, here is the Java script to extract the constants pool.

```
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool;

class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ClassParser c = new ClassParser(args[0]);
            JavaClass j = c.parse();
            ConstantPool cp = j.getConstantPool();
            System.out.format(cp.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { return; }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not [goign to be easy](https://shipilev.net/blog/2015/black-magic-method-dispatch). You will need to look at the assembly code

Comment: @Eugene I'm ready and willing :)

Comment: yeah, I have been through that a few times and its very nice to understand those things. all the best!

Comment: Java doesn't have virtual function tables. It has method tables, but they don't work the same way.

Comment: @user207421 the concept *must* be similar for virtual methods dispatch to work, if you can provide a detailed answer that would be great.

Comment: Maybe `Java Object Layout` will help you with what you want.  With `JOL` you can check all the object layout and information. I hope it helps :) 
Check an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-measuring-object-sizes)

Answer (score 3):

Post from Lalith Suresh [3]

> At the bytecode level, the invokevirtual operation is what triggers
> the Java equivalent of a C++ virtual method call [1]. As per the
> specification, the operation accepts an index (two actually, but it is
> combined to get a single value) which is used to get a reference to a
> method and a reference to the class in which the method is to be
> found. In HotSpot [2], this corresponds to a vtable index within the
> target class, resolving which the intended target method can be
> invoked. Depending on the class hierarchy, each class may have a
> differently sized vtable, and child classes that override methods of a
> parent can re-use vtable.
>
> However, in the JIT compiled code, the vtable calling sequence is
> typically not used. HotSpot performs inline caching, wherein the code
> optimistically assumes that the target of a virtual method always
> points to the same implementation (meaning the call site is
> monomorphic). In this case, a check is inserted into the code to
> verify whether the assumption actually holds (that is, the target
> hasn't changed), and then control is passed directly to the target
> method without involving any vtable lookups, akin to how a so-called
> 'unlinked' call site works. Loosely put, if this assumptions fails
> enough times, the code falls back to the long-winded vtable lookup
> approach.

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual

[2] https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/VirtualCalls

[3] https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-virtual-method-table-implemented-in-Java